# Does this imply existence of limit?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

According to the sum rule, the $\lim(a_n+b_n)=\lim(a_n)+\lim(b_n)$.

If I know that $\lim(a_n+b_n)=L$, and $\lim(b_n)=b$, can I say $\lim(a_n)=L-b$?

Is that enough to prove that $a_n$ truly is convergent and it's limit is $L-b$?

Thanks and sorry for the non-LaTex...

Comment: Yes, you can say that. In pedantic terms: the map $(x_n)\longmapsto \lim x_n$ is a linear functional on the vector space of converging sequences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you know that the sequence $\{a_n + b_n\}$ is convergent and that the sequence $\{b_n\}$ is convergent. The sum/difference of two convergent sequences is convergent so the sequence given by $a_n = (a_n + b_n) - b_n$ is convergent.

Also, you know that the limit is
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n = \lim_{n\to \infty} a_n+b_n - b_n = \lim_{n\to \infty} a_n + b_n - \lim_{n\to \infty}b_n = L - b.
$$

Comment: @user2190298: Glad to help.

Comment: about that last line (just to make sure) you're saying that I can write:
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n
$$
before I even know it is convergent?

Comment: @user2190298: Well, before that line I actually first made the note that $\{a_n\}$ is convergent.

Comment: Oh, yeah, sorry.

Comment: @user2190298: No problem. Feel free to ask more questions.

Answer (score 0):

User2190298, there is another rule: *if $\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n=b$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty} (-b_n)=-b$*.
 
Now apply the sum rule to the limits $\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_n+b_n)$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}(-b_n)$.
 
And yes this is enough for a proof that $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=L-b$.